# Type Error running feature in Rail's Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, cucumber, geospatial

I'm trying to run Cucumber for my Rails application and keep getting this error:

```
> superclass mismatch for class Point (TypeError)
```

There's a huge stack trace from this error, but it does not point to anything specific except a missing requirement.  Here's the trace:

---

> rake features (in /Users/rob/blue/blue_web)
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   -I "/Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/lib:lib"
>   "/Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/cucumber"
>   --color --tags ~@wip --strict --format pretty --drb
>   features/manage_logins.feature
>   WARNING: No DRb server is running.
>   Running features locally: superclass
>   mismatch for class Point (TypeError)
>   /Users/rob/blue/blue_web/app/models/point.rb:1
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `gem_original_require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   polyglot_original_require'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.2.9/lib/polyglot.rb:70:in
>   `require'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in`
>   require'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:265:in
>   `require_or_load'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:224:in`
>   depend_on'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:136:in
>   `require_dependency'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:414:in`
>   load_application_classes'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:413:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:413:in`
>   load_application_classes'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:411:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:411:in`
>   load_application_classes'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:197:in
>   `process'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in`
>   send'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.4/lib/initializer.rb:113:in
>   `run'
>   /Users/rob/blue/blue_web/config/environment.rb:16
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `polyglot_original_require'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.2.9/lib/polyglot.rb:70:in`
>   require' ./features/support/env.rb:7
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/spork-0.7.2/lib/spork.rb:14:in
>   `prefork' ./features/support/env.rb:4
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   gem_original_require'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `polyglot_original_require'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/polyglot-0.2.9/lib/polyglot.rb:70:in`
>   require'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:107:in
>   `load_code_file'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:48:in`
>   step_definitions_for'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:90:in
>   `load_code_file'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:82:in`
>   load_code_files'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:81:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:81:in`
>   load_code_files'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:46:in
>   `execute!'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:24:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/rob/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.102/bin/cucumber:9
>   rake aborted! Command failed with
>   status (1):
>   [/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/...]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this problem, it was a class name **conflict** with the mySQL geoSpatial plug-in and my schema.

I had a class named Point and everything was happy.  Then I added (the very cool) geoSpatial plug-in to use mySQL's geo index features.  This plug-in also defines a Point class.

The conflict was causing Cucumber to fail.

If you are seeing this error in your own application, look for duplicates!

Comment: What kind of lame-brained library adds classes to the global scope?  this is what Module and namespaces are for.

Comment: I had a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736747/how-to-resolve-rails-model-namespace-collision) -- highly annoying. Gem authors need to take more care to avoid cluttering up the top-level namespace.

Comment: Yes but you'll also need to namespace any tables created too, don't forget. Shouldn't be a problem if the gem is configurable enough.