# How to resolve Rails model namespace collision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, cucumber, collision

The story so far:

I have a rails app with a model named "Term". All is well until trying to install Cucumber. Upon running

```
rake cucumber
```

I get

```
Term is not a class (TypeError)
```

This happens because Cucumber includes another gem, 'term-ansicolor' (to do the nifty colored text output in the console), and term-ansicolor defines a module named "Term". Cucumber includes term-ansicolor before including the Rails models, thus "Term" is already defined as a module when loading the "Term" model. Top-level modules and classes cannot have the same names in Ruby, thus the collision.

Preferring not to rename the model, I set about patching the term-ansicolor gem. This proved harder than I thought. I changed the Term module name to "ANSITerm", but I can't figure out how to get Cucumber to load my modified gem, which I've put into RAILS_ROOT/vendor/gems/term-ansicolor.

Any ideas? Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: I just ran into this *exact* issue, I have a model named Term as well and just installed cucumber. Good thing I searched for that error before spending hours trying to figure out what was going on! Thank you so much for posting this, I will be following your solution!

Comment: I'm glad this was helpful. Keep in mind you have to maintain your patched gems going forward, so renaming the model might be easier.

Comment: I've actually commented on this cucumber bug here: https://rspec.lighthouseapp.com/projects/16211-cucumber/tickets/489 and I'm working on getting your patched term-ansicolor from github integrated with a patched cucumber so that we don't have to maintain the patched gem; but yeah, I have renamed my model in the meantime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions:

1) Change your app's Term model to be something else.

2) Patch term-ansicolor to have a namespaced Term and use that gem instead.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did:

`sudo gem uninstall term-ansicolor`
`sudo gem uninstall cucumber`

Download sources for term-ansicolor and cucumber from github
Search term-ansicolor source for `"module Term"` and replace with `"module ANSITerm"`
Search cucumber source for `"include Term"` and replace with `"include ANSITerm"`
Search cucumber source for `"::Term"` and replace with `"::ANSITerm"`

`sudo gem install term-ansicolor` from my local repository
`sudo gem install cucumber` from my local repository

Now I have two gems to maintain, but that seems easier than changing all the model references in my app.

Comments/suggestions welcome.

Comment: just FYI, there's also Gherkin. Cucumber relies on Gherkin, Gherkin relies on Term-Ansicolor. Overall idea is good, and will work for several people, but everyone will be still doing that workaround every time he faces that thing. The better thing would be to fix it once in Cucumber/Gherkin and forget about it for ages.

Comment: I don't really like this solution. In retrospect, have you found a better approach? I've had similar problems with 'Task' which I believe Rake uses, had to rename to Taskee.

Answer (score 3):

I did get a namespace collision with my application model Node and Capybara::Node in my specs. It was sufficient for me to explicitly state toplevel namespace in specs to fix the problem:

```
it "should find the specified node scoped under the current user" do
  ::Node.should have_received(:find_by_id_for_user).with(node.id, user)
end
```